POST or PUT on the same endpoint
I want to create an endpoint /message/{id} where id can be optional. Basically if there is no id it will be a Post request to create a new message. And if there is an id it will be a Put request.
I need to only have one function who can achieve the both types of request, I can't split it in two request, it's for a technical exercice and the subject is like this.
I want to do something like this :
  ...("/message/{id}")
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) // it need to be different if it's a POST or a PUT
  public Mono<MessageDTO> createOrUpdateMessage(
    @RequestBody MessageRequest messageRequest
  ) {
    // if no id
    return messageService.createMessage(messageRequest);
    // if id
    return messageService.updateMessage(...);
  }

I can't fine the right config annotation to do that with Spring Boot online ...
How would you approach this problem ?

That won't work. Just create 2 endpoints. /message for @PostMapping and @PutMapping for /messages/{id}. I don't see the issue with creating 2 methods to do this. Else it simply isn't possible to differentiate between a PUT and POST anyway. Unless you do the request handling etc. yourself.

For the time being, I've decided to keep the two separate so as not to get bogged down in this problem. And depending on the answers I get, I'll set up an “alternative” solution to stick to the subject of the exercise I've been given.

Try this:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/message")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/{id}", ""}, method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<MessageDTO>> createOrUpdateMessage(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) Long id,
        @RequestBody MessageRequest messageRequest
    ) {
        if (id == null) {
            // Handle POST (Create)
            Mono<MessageDTO> createdMessage = messageService.createMessage(messageRequest);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(createdMessage, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } else {
            // Handle PUT (Update)
            Mono<MessageDTO> updatedMessage = messageService.updateMessage(id, messageRequest);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}


It's pretty much what I want, but I didn't put a route annotation at the top of MessageController only @RestController 'cause I want /messages endpoint to retrieve all the messages and /message/{id} for create or update a message inside my controller. So if I understand your proposition, I juste need to modify : value = {"/{id}", ""} into value = {"/message/{id}", "/message"} Right ?

This will both allow POST or PUT with/without an id, which is not what the requirement was.

Maybe it's possible to do only a PUT request with an optional id to create or update ? Or PUT is strictly for update ?

@GuillaumeLagouy Yes this is achievable, but the suggestion here would be to keep it different and that will align with solid principles.

EDIT Unfortunately it doesn't work. Spring recognize only first @XXXMapping annotation.
Surprisingly you can have both annotation, so:
    @PutMapping("/message/{id}")
    @PostMapping("/message")
    public void myFunnyMethod(@PathVariable(required = false) String id){

    }


Oh neat ! And it's work without any side effect ?

I don't know. Never used it like this.

This would still allow a PUT request to /message/ as the id is optional. While it (might) work for the 80% case it still allows PUT requests.
